# Can't avoid duplicated results in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

i have used all solutions proposed on stackoverflow to resolve my probleme but it is still not resolved:

i need to get bid users ordered by plan_id without duplication. this is the query i used:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT b.*, u.username, u.name, s.plan_id, s.user_id FROM #__jb_bid b

    "INNER JOIN #__users u ON b.user_id=u.id ".
    "INNER JOIN #__jb_plan_subscr s ON b.user_id=s.user_id ".
    "WHERE b.project_id =".$id."".
    "ORDER BY s.plan_id";
```

i am using Joomla 3 and a personalized component, i have this structure:

## __jb_bid TABLE:

```
------------------------------------
|id | user_id | project_id |
|-----------------------------------
|1  | 22      |     1      |
|2  | 24      |     1      |
|3  | 23      |     1      |
|4  | 25      |     1      |
|5  | 26      |     2      |
------------------------------------
```

## __jb_users TABLE:

```
------------------------------------
|id | username    | name           |
|-----------------------------------
|22  | username22   |     name22      |
|23  | username23   |     name23      |
|24  | username24   |     name24      |
|25  | username25   |     name25      |
|26  | username26   |     name26      |
|27  | username27   |     name27      |
------------------------------------
```

## __jb_plan_subscr TABLE: (user_id 22 have two plans)

```
------------------------------------
|id | user_id    | plan_id    |
|-----------------------------------
|1  | 22         |     1      |
|2  | 22         |     2      |
|3  | 23         |     1      |
|4  | 24         |     1      |
|5  | 25         |     1      |
------------------------------------
```

The result of the query is:

```
username22
username24
username25
username22
username23
```

Thanks

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Please include your desire output. You know `user_id = 22` has two plan but dont say which one you want to use.

Comment: please ignore :  AND $bidderQuery AND $ndaQuery

Comment: I ignore that, But still need to know what output you want Please update your question and let me know

Comment: hi Juan Carlos Oropeza, i want to use the highest plan_id value

Comment: Your table `__jb_users` doesnt have any `user_id` match on the other tables :(

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers. [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: __jb_users data is for exemple only, lets say:
------------------------------------
|id | username    | name           |
|-----------------------------------
|22  | username22   |     name22      |
|23  | username23   |     name23      |
|34  | username24   |     name24      |
------------------------------------

Comment: Dont be lazy, Please write a proper example so we have something to work with. Dont write it on comment. Edit your question and include the output. I dont like waste my time trying to guess what you want

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4994f/2)**

```
SELECT b.*, u.username, u.name, s.plan_id, s.user_id 
FROM (SELECT `user_id`, MAX(`plan_id`) `plan_id`
      FROM __jb_plan_subscr 
      GROUP BY `user_id`
     ) s
INNER JOIN  __jb_bid b
  ON  b.user_id = s.user_id 
INNER JOIN __jb_users u 
  ON b.user_id = u.id
WHERE project_id = 1
ORDER BY s.plan_id;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| id | user_id | project_id |  username |  name | plan_id | user_id |
|----|---------|------------|-----------|-------|---------|---------|
|  2 |      24 |          1 | username3 | name3 |       1 |      24 |
|  1 |      22 |          1 | username1 | name1 |       2 |      22 |
```

Comment: thank you Juan Carlos Oropeza, but in your output user_id =24 is duplicated, and it's my problem

Comment: Is duplicated because I didnt filter by `project_id` if you add `WHERE project_id = 1` you get the result you want